# Why the output of this code is 1 (infinite)?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

**code**

```
main( )
{
 int i ;
 for ( i = 1 ; i <= 5 ; printf ( "\n%d", i ) ) ;
     i++ ;
}
```

**output**

`1` infinite times.

Comment: The syntax is incorrect. Remove the semicolon after for. i++ is outside of the `for` body because of the ";"

Comment: @NellieDanielyan The syntax is correct ;-) Likely intended as a test/teaser.

Comment: @P.P you got it. It's a question in the book "Let us C" by Yashwant Kanetkar.

Comment: @ShivamSingh It's good that you mentioned your source - "Let us C" is not considered as a good book to learn C. It has numerous bugs, makes bad assumptions about implementations, etc. See [The definitive C book guide and list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/562303/1275169).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a trailing `;` at the end of the loop that effectively makes your code:

```
for ( i = 1 ; i <= 5 ; printf ( "\n%d", i ) )
{
}
i++;
```